# unable to write multi-index dataframe to excel

Tags: pandas

I want to write a multi-index dataframe to excel:

```
col = [['info', '', 'key'], ['alert', 'date', 'price'], ['alert', 'date', 'amount']]
df = pd.DataFrame(columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(col))
df.loc[0, :] = np.random.random(3)
df.to_excel('data.xlsx', index = False)
```

However, an error occurs:

```
NotImplementedError: Writing to Excel with MultiIndex columns and no index ('index'=False) is not yet implemented.
```

I checked pandas version : `pd.__version__` and the result is `'0.25.3'`.

How to solve the problem?

Thank you.

[image]

Comment: How important is for you to export directly as xlsx? If not very important, you can export as CSV first and then load into Excel.

Comment: Can you show me the code?

Comment: Checkout this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17349574/pandas-write-multiindex-rows-with-to-csv

Comment: It has been said that this problem has been solved in version 0.17.0 in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33633858/pandas-error-writing-as-excel-with-a-multiindex-is-not-yet-implemented. But why do I have this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After searching the web, I used `pywin32` to solve the problem.

```
import win32com.client as win32
df.to_excel('data.xlsx', index = True)
excel = win32.gencache.EnsureDispatch('Excel.Application')
excel.DisplayAlerts = False
wb = excel.Workbooks.Open('data.xlsx')
excel.Visible = True
ws = wb.Worksheets('Sheet1')
ws.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete()
wb.SaveAs('data.xlsx')
excel.Application.Quit()
```

Answer (score 1):

To remove the extra column, try resetting the index to 'info' column.

```
df.set_index(['info'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

`df.to_excel(r'data.xlsx', index = True)`

ref: https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/issues/11292#issuecomment-447150410

Comment: if setting index to True, there will be an extra column in the excel file. How to remove that column?

Comment: Please refer to the revised question.

Comment: Can anyone help?

Comment: Adding comment to come back later. Also, I am also waiting on a answer to this question.